# Opening the app when terminated with firebase dynamic link crashes the app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have integrated firebase dynamic links with my app. It works fine with foreground and background states. However, the app crashes when I open it on terminated state. Here is my code to handle dynamic links

```
 static Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
    try {
      // terminated state
      final PendingDynamicLinkData initLink =
          await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
      if (initLink != null) {
        print('init link $initLink');
        final Uri deeplink = initLink?.link;
        if (deeplink != null) {
          print('routing');
          // routing(deeplink, deeplink.queryParameters);
        } else {
          print('deep link is null');
        }
      } else {
        print('init link is null');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('error getting link $e');
    }

    // background and foreground states
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) async {
      final Uri deeplink = dynamicLinkData.link;
      final queryParams = deeplink.queryParameters;
      if (deeplink != null) {
        routing(deeplink, queryParams);
      } else {
        print('listen link is null');
      }
    }).onError((error) {
      print('onLink error');
      print(error.message);
    });
  }
```

The dynamic link gets printed and it is not null, but what I get is a blank screen, half of it black and the other half is red.

Note: routing is a function that navigates to a specific path.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: could you solve this ?